# Formal parameter of the form **keyword

Tags: python, keyword

What exactly is the purpose of the "formal parameter of the form **keyword"? I put it in quotations, because that's what its referred to as in the docs, but I've had difficulty finding information on it and thought that maybe there's a formal term for it.

From what I understand, it allows the user to do something like

```
def foo(**keywords):
   for i in keywords:
       print(i, ":", keywords[i])

foo(val1="1", val2="2", val3="3")
```

Output:

```
val1 : 1
val2 : 2
val3 : 3
```

What exactly is the advantage of this? Wouldn't passing a dictionary variable work better for ease of understanding?

Comment: Where exactly in the docs do you see it called that? Link, please.

Comment: @agf 

[py2.x docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)

[py3.x docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Comment: "formal parameter" refer to a parameter as it appears in the function definition, rather than the value associated with that parameter when the function is called -- the "actual parameter". So "formal parameter of the form..." just means "**keyword when used as a function parameter". That's not part of the name of that type of argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a dictionary, calling a function would look like this:

```
myfunv({"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"})
```

Using **kwargs this becomes

```
myfunc(key1="value1", key2="value2")
```

Many people prefer the latter.

This construct is also very useful when you are transparently passing arguments to another function or class. For example, I use this a lot when subclassing Tkinter widgets. I want to support all of the options of the base class, so I code it like this:

```
class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        <more code here>
```

This allows me to support all the same arguments without having to explicitly list them all.

Answer (score 1):

One use is when you want to forward parameters along. For example:

```
def do_some_work(kwd1=None, kwd2=None, ...):
    ....

def intermediate_function(some_other_params, **kwargs):
    ...
    do_some_work(**kwargs)

def main():
    intermediate_function(some_other_params, kwd1=5, kwd2='foo')
```

That way if you add a parameter to `do_some_work`, you don't have to add it to both the definition of `intermediate_function` and the call to `do_some_work` within there.

---

Another place it gets used is in Django's signal handlers. When you write a handler, you write it in the form

```
def handle_signal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
```

so that the API can be changed to pass additional arguments in the future without requiring users to go add parameters to a bunch of methods that won't use them.

Answer (score 0):

With this construct, the caller can use standard keyword arguments.

Comment: The caller can use keyword arguments, as if you had defined them the "normal" way in your function definition, without needing any knowledge that you are accessing them in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Historically Parameter passing has been either through positional or via keyword argument. Passing complex objects as parameters is a relatively recent addition and people are more comfortable in passing values as parameters

1. Its simple
2. Readability

Now extending the concept, passing variable positional and keywords arguments when supported gives rise to the above construct.

Interestingly passing a dictionary is still possible though the construct, but the intent becomes less obvious which responsible programmer wouldn't want.